# Reactjs - Video component | how to load the video while showing a placeholder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, preload

I've made a Video component that's using the React.Suspense component to display a placeholder while loading the video. The thing is I have the impression that it doesn't work at all. When I put the network in "slow 3G", I have a long white screen and when everything is loaded I see the placeholder for a second, then the video.

Does anyone has a better way of doing so ?

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import Image from "next/image";

type Props = {
  src: string;
  placeholder: string;
  type: string;
};

type PlaceholderProps = {
  placeholder: string;
};

const Placeholder = (props: PlaceholderProps) => {
  const { placeholder } = props;
  return (
    <div className="w-full h-full">
      <Image
        src={placeholder}
        layout="fill"
        objectFit="cover"
        placeholder="blur"
        blurDataURL={placeholder}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default function Video(props: Props) {
  const { src, type, placeholder } = props;

  return (
    <>
      <Suspense fallback={<Placeholder placeholder={placeholder} />}>
        <video
          preload="metadata"
          loop
          autoPlay
          muted
          className={`w-full h-full object-cover`}
        >
          <source src={src} type={`video/${type}`} />
        </video>
      </Suspense>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different phases for a React application to be rendered in a browser .

> long white screen

The browser will need to download all the assets (HTML, CSS and JavaScript) from some remote locations, something like a server or CDN. AT this phase, this has nothing to do with React.

> I see the placeholder for a second, then the video.

When your JavaScript bundle is loaded, Browser will start loading your React application and that's where you see your placeholder.

---

In general, I would say "slow 3G" is pretty slow. Depends on where you are, the average speed is probably faster. That being said, to get your website to load faster, you can:

1. Reduce amount of bytes the browser needs to load. Smaller JavaScript bundle and better compressed image/video assets.
2. Server side render your page can help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but I hope this still helps anyone who's encountering this issue.

The main problem with this approach: `<video>` inside a `<Suspense>`, is that the video is not considered a "Suspense-enabled data source."  [Learn more](https://react.dev/reference/react/Suspense#displaying-a-fallback-while-content-is-loading)

I also tried turning my `<Video>` component to a LazyComponent with '`next/dynamic`' however, that still didn't work.

This is how I approached this problem: **CSS**

Basically, I added `position:absolute;` to both the fallback `<Image>` and `<Video>`. In other words, they're both occupying the same space in the div.

Then, the video should have a higher `z-index` than the image. This way, the image usually loads first which will become the fallback while the video is still downloading. Once the video loads, it will render on top of the fallback `<Image>`.

Here's my code:

video.module.css

```
.video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -50;
}
```

fallback.module.css

```
.image {
    z-index: -100;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

page.tsx

```
<Image
    src='img.jpg'
    alt='image alt'
    priority
    className={styles.image}
    width={1920}
    height={1080}
    objectFit='contain'
/>
<video autoPlay loop muted className={styles.video}>
    <source src={src} type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

You just have to make sure that the `<Image>` and `<Video>` have the same size and position in the DOM.